# What is the favorite time of day for Canadians?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**What is the favorite time of day for Canadians?**

Not sure how hard this will be...

Hint 1:  Happens twice a day.  To the minute.

Hint 2:  Think digital clocks.

Hint 3:  If you don't believe me, consider 1996.

NEW:

Hint 4:  Technically, it is something that almost happened in 1996.

More Hint(s):

> Hint 5: Something was almost re-named in 1996.

Comment: From personal experience, the answer is beer o'clock.

Comment: Nah, it's beer thirty

Comment: every single time happens twice a day if you consider 12 hour clocks. none does, if you consider 24 hour clocks

Comment: @njzk2 that is the hint I believe that it is some time related to the 12 hour clock.  I was going to guess it was something to do with the toonie (2 dollar coin introduced in 1996) could also technically fit hint 4 as it was announced in 1995 and some coins were minted in 1995 but it wasn't until 1996 it was put into circulation.

Comment: No no.  It just means that the time occurs twice a day on a 12 hour clock, e.g, 1:23 AM and 1:23 PM.

Comment: but all times happen twice a day, so the hint is not really hinting, unless I am missing something

Comment: 2:23 PM does not happen twice a day.  Nor does 14:35.

Comment: @Jiminion but 2:23 does occur twice a day, in the AM and PM.

Comment: I bet it's something to do with the World Cup....US beat Canada that year. But I like the "Bob" hypothesis

Comment: @Ryan,  I was just trying to indicate that AM/PM was not relevant to determining the answer, and I failed pretty badly.....  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit:

My new answer is:

> 8:08 (Bob)

because

> In 1996, after the Northwest Territories split off from Nunavut, there was discussion about changing the name of the territory. One of the suggestions for renaming the territory was "Bob," and the suggestion gained widespread public support. In the end, the Northwest Territories kept its name.

---

Previous answer (incorrect):

> 1:16

Because

> In 1995, Quebec voted for independence from Canada. The results were (according to Wikipedia) 49.42 For, 50.58 against. 50.58 - 49.42 = 1.16, hence 1:16. It occurs twice a day on a digital clock if you discount the AM/PM.

Although,

> In my experience as an expat living in Canada, people tend to use 24 hour time fairly frequently here, so I have a nagging suspicion that the twice a day thing hints at something else.

Comment: Nice try.  The twice a day thing just means the number shows up twice a day on 12 hour time.

Comment: I guess you got it.  The newer edit was just a clean up.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I wasn't happy with my copy/paste straight from Wikipedia.

Comment: ok, but how is that a "favorite time"?

Comment: So it's a "Boaty McBoatface" kind of thing...?

Comment: @Paul, Yes, the Canadians were far ahead of the curve on that one.

Comment: @njzk2 8:08 on a digital clock - 8:08 AM or 8:08 PM

Comment: @MorganG yes. Time. But "favorite", that's a stretch.

Comment: Personally I prefer Doug

Answer (score 18):

Can it be

> 8:08?

Because it resembles an

> ice hockey field 
>  
>  [image]

Not sure how it fits the twice a day though

Comment: The time 8:08 occurs twice a day - AM & PM.

Comment: @Mithrandir Thought about that, but on my digital clock it shows differently for PM. And each minute is like that, so that hint is not very helpfull.

Comment: It rules out 24 hour clock times.

Comment: Very creative answer.  I can't give it to you though.

Comment: Mithrandir's first comment is on the mark.

Comment: I'm sure it's hockey related... in 1996 Canada almost won the Hockey World Cup, losing to USA in the final.

Comment: @PaulEllery Canda won the cup in 2004, so I don't think so.

Comment: Not hockey related (that I know of).  But look at this answer (but not the explanation) more carefully.

Comment: 8:08 could be read as BOB... so maybe we're looking for a similar 3 or 4 letter word that we could write on a digital clock... that's related to Canada?  Not sure where 1996 comes in though

Comment: 8:08 appears the same whether you turn it rightside up or upside down

Comment: Paul is so warm the rink is starting to melt.

Answer (score 7):

Canadians reputedly say 'eh' a lot, which on an old digital clock (or my casio calculator) looks like 43 upside-down.

At the risk of generalising, they also like to say two-four.

Comment: Or here in BC [4:20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/420_(cannabis_culture))

Comment: I thought that was confined to the less salubrious parts of Vancouver. hadn't appreciated that it was province-wide

Answer (score 6):

The time is

> 8:08

Because

> It could be interpreted as "BOB", one of the proposed new names for the Northwest Territories (a campaign that was underway in 1996).

Comment: Got it!  But Paul probably deserves an assist.  Good job!

Comment: Looks like he was pretty close, yeah. I didn't read any of the comments, actually.

Comment: Technically I did provide the correct answer 5 minutes before Ian did

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell.  According to the edits, Ian is a bit sooner.

Comment: @Jiminion, no the mouseover for the revision history shows that Morgan had the correct answer 5 minutes before me. The answer was edited again to clean up some of the text after I had answered.

Comment: Yep, I fixed it again.  (I'm glad they don't penalize for moving the check mark around....)

Comment: I don't understand why this would be a favourite time. I'm half Canadian, but I don't half get it :-(

Comment: @Strawberry: Essentially, this was the "Boaty McBoatface" of 1996, but with the name of a whole province instead of a research vessel. It's an entertaining factoid, but I agree that "favourite" is a stretch.

Answer (score 5):

There's always

> 7:01, which is Canada Day (July 1 = 7/01).

However, in 1996,

> The Winnipeg Jets officially became the Phoenix Coyotes on July 1, which would disqualify it as a "favorite" day/time for myself and anyone else who grew up in Winnipeg.

So I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Interesting answer!  Sorry about the loss of the Jets.

Comment: It's OK — another team moved *to* Winnipeg 3–4 years ago and started playing under the "Jets" name, so that wound is healed somewhat.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Could it be :

> 02:15 AM/PM

Explainations :

> Looking at [what happened in 1996 in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_in_Canada), I found about [National Flag of Canada Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Flag_of_Canada_Day). This event occured on February 15th, hence my answer. As for the twice a day, a digital clock would display this time twice (AM/PM).

Comment: Not quite.  But a good answer.

Comment: You're looking for something that nearly happened, and why would that be their favourite time?

Answer (score 3):

> In 1996, Reform Party PM Stephen Harper, the same politician who later became Canada's Prime Minister, introduced a private member's bill to have Canada Day (July 1st) renamed back to Dominion Day, which is what it had been called until 1982. The bill was defeated. If the bill had passed, then the day would have been renamed; thus Canada Day was almost renamed in 1996.

Thus:

> Since July 1st is, numerically, 7-1, maybe our favorite time is 7:01?

Comment: Happy belated Canada Day!  I remember your coinage all changed for a year in 1967.  I especially remember the fish on the dime.

Answer (score 2):

May be it is:

> 11:11

because

> With 22:22, it is the time of the day when the same digit appears 4 times on a digital clock.
>  But it' probably not the answer: I have no clues about 1996, or Canadians' favorite time of day.

Comment: Interesting answer.  No the right one, though.